# How to display rdfs:comment of DBpedia resource

Tags: jena, dbpedia, rdfs

I have Questions and Answers classes in my owl file. This is a sort of quiz game and if user chooses wrong answer, I want to display the `rdfs:comment` about that resource from [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/resource/DBpedia). Like, What is capital of [Spain](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Spain)? here I include `rdfs:comment` of [Madrid](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Madrid). Which country has more population? here I include `rdfs:comment` of [China](http://dbpedia.org/resource/China).

So if user selects wrong answer, it means user does not know about that resource and I want to explain it in form of `rdfs:comment`.

How can I associate and then display `rdfs:comment` with each question? Can I download all required `rdfs:comment` resources in a pdf or other format so that user can later study it after completing quiz or if there is a way to display the `rdfs:comment` during the quiz? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: We don't have enough information. What tools are you using? What have you tried? What have your results been? You can always `SELECT` a given predicate/attribute (e.g., `rdfs:comment`) of a given subject/entity (e.g., `http://dbpedia.org/resource/China`), so such is always displayable, if you have live access to DBpedia...

Comment: @TallTed, how can I download the rdfs:comment of various resources in a form of a document? How to use Construct query to download and store it locally?

Comment: What kind of document?  You can run any SPARQL query (`SELECT`, `CONSTRUCT`, or otherwise) through curl or similar tools, just as you would through the browser-based SPARQL form, and you have just as much freedom in content-negotiation — so you can request HTML, or CSV, or Turtle, or various other forms… You don't need a `CONSTRUCT` query for anything you've described, but you left out many details, so maybe there's something I don't know.